# Problem with roslaunch on rc.local startup

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried launching some nodes on startup via rc.local, but I have the following errors on some of the startups:

```
[   45.809342] rc.local[661]: RLException: ERROR: could not contact master [http://localhost:11311]                                
[   45.821666] rc.local[661]: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file                                                     
[   45.844191] rc.local[661]: ... logging to /root/.ros/log/3b1cabe6-64e9-11e9-8f36-74e1828a3ed5/roslaunch-arm-945.log                        
[   45.845040] rc.local[661]: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.                                                    
[   45.845630] rc.local[661]: Press Ctrl-C to interrupt                                                                                       
[   45.846329] rc.local[661]: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.                                                               
[   45.846840] rc.local[661]: 2;/home/tucer/catkin_ws/src/electronicload/launch/launcher.launch                                               
[   45.847310] rc.local[661]: started roslaunch server http://arm:45779/                                                                      
[   45.847892] rc.local[661]: SUMMARY                                                                                                         
[   45.860883] rc.local[661]: ========                                                                                                        
[   45.864314] rc.local[661]: PARAMETERS                                                                                                      
[   45.865892] rc.local[661]:  * /rosdistro: melodic                                                                                          
[   45.868293] rc.local[661]:  * /rosversion: 1.14.3                                                                                          
[   45.876385] rc.local[661]: NODES                                                                                                           
[   45.877925] rc.local[661]:   /                                                                                                             
[   45.880247] rc.local[661]:     LCD (electronicload/LCD.py)                                                                                 
[   45.882944] rc.local[661]:     controller (electronicload/controller.py)                                                                   
[   45.888258] rc.local[661]:     logger_to_file (electronicload/logger_to_file.py)                                                           
[   45.892181] rc.local[661]:     sensors (electronicload/sensors.py)                                                                         
[   45.893536] rc.local[661]:     shutdown (electronicload/shutdown.py)                                                                       
[   45.894667] rc.local[661]: auto-starting new master                                                                                        
[   45.900240] rc.local[661]: process[master]: started with pid [1175]                                                                        
[   46.031643] rc.local[661]: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                              
[   46.036751] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rosmaster", line 35, in <module>                                                   
[   46.039083] rc.local[661]:     rosmaster.rosmaster_main()                                                                                  
[   46.040722] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 84, in rosmaster_main             
[   46.045008] rc.local[661]:     configure_logging()                                                                                         
[   46.048811] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 58, in configure_logging          
[   46.051817] rc.local[661]:     _log_filename = rosgraph.roslogging.configure_logging('rosmaster', logging.DEBUG, filename=filename)        
[   46.057809] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 185, in configure_logging    
[   46.063184] rc.local[661]:     logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)                                      
[   46.070380] rc.local[661]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 85, in fileConfig                                           
[   46.074387] rc.local[661]:     handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)                                                                
[   46.075661] rc.local[661]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 163, in _install_handlers                                   
[   46.081225] rc.local[661]:     h = klass(*args)                                                                                            
[   46.082611] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 230, in __init__             
[   46.083944] rc.local[661]:     from rospy.rostime import get_time, is_wallclock                                                            
[   46.085346] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>                   
[   46.088288] rc.local[661]:     from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \                                                              
[   46.089780] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 60, in <module>                     
[   46.092281] rc.local[661]:     import rospy.impl.init                                                                                      
[   46.096286] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/init.py", line 54, in <module>                  
[   46.097914] rc.local[661]:     from .tcpros import init_tcpros                                                                             
[   46.099095] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros.py", line 45, in <module>                
[   46.103889] rc.local[661]:     import rospy.impl.tcpros_service                                                                            
[   46.105827] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 51, in <module>        
[   46.108284] rc.local[661]:     from rospy.service import _Service, ServiceException                                                        
[   46.112301] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/service.py", line 45, in <module>                    
[   46.113780] rc.local[661]:     from rospy.impl.registration import set_service_manager, Registration, get_registration_listeners           
[   46.114943] rc.local[661]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/registration.py", line 35, in <module>          
[   46.118278] rc.local[661]:     """Internal use: handles maintaining registrations with master via internal listener APIs"""                
[   46.119717] rc.local[661]: KeyboardInterrupt                                                                                               
[   47.226949] rc.local[661]: [master] killing on exit
```

These error does not appear to happen when I reboot, only when I poweroff/shutdown and since the echo commands on rc.local work, I figured the problem is roslaunch specific.
Here's my rc.local file:

```
#! /bin/bash
bash /home/tucer/startup.bash&
exit 0
```

and the startup.bash file:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "The penguin took off..."

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source /home/tucer/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
echo "...the penguin sourced both bash files for ros with his penguin nades..."
roslaunch electronicload launcher.launch
echo "...the penguin landed safely."
```

All ros commands work when the system has fully booted, rc.local works as intended when executed after boot with command:

```
sudo /etc/rc.local start
```

It only doesn't work when from powered off state, it boots (reminder it works when it reboots). My setup is beaglebone black with Ubuntu 18.04.2 image supplied by
[elinux](https://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu) .

EDIT: After some extra tests it turns out this problem occurs only when I have an Ethernet cable connecting the BeagleBone to a laptop (currently running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS). Any thoughts on that matter? Having an Ethernet connection still does not create any problems with running roslaunch AFTER boot up.

EDIT2: Following Delb's suggestion the startup.bash file changed to:

```
#! /bin/bash
export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311/"
export ROS_HOSTNAME="localhost"


echo "The penguin took off..."

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source /home/tucer/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
echo "...the penguin sourced both bash files for ros with his penguin nades..."
roslaunch electronicload launcher.launch
echo "...the penguin landed safely."
```

I also tried using a fixed IP that is being used in the connection between laptop-beaglebone, but since the set up connection is "shared-to-other-computers" from the ubuntu laptop, this ip can only be obtained when the connection establishes (making it non-existent when the connection is absent). In that case the startup.bash was:

```
#! /bin/bash
export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://10.42.0.164:11311/"
export ROS_HOSTNAME="10.42.0.164"


echo "The penguin took off..."

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source /home/tucer/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
echo "...the penguin sourced both bash files for ros with his penguin nades..."
roslaunch electronicload launcher.launch
echo "...the penguin landed safely."
```

In both cases, even though MASTER and HOSTNAME used the same IP, errors still occurred (mentioning the localhost startup.bash version errors):

```
[   45.794378] rc.local[697]: RLException: ERROR: could not contact master [http://localhost:11311/]                               
[   45.801929] rc.local[697]: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file                                                     
[   45.829992] rc.local[697]: ... logging to /root/.ros/log/bb6138b2-6cbe-11e9-ba8e-74e1828a3ed5/roslaunch-arm-948.log                        
[   45.830816] rc.local[697]: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.                                                    
[   45.831640] rc.local[697]: Press Ctrl-C to interrupt                                                                                       
[   45.833944] rc.local[697]: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.                                                               
[   45.840285] rc.local[697]: 2;/home/tucer/catkin_ws/src/electronicload/launch/launcher.launch                                               
[   45.844272] rc.local[697]: started roslaunch server http://localhost:41159/                                                                
[   45.848198] rc.local[697]: SUMMARY                                                                                                         
[   45.850096] rc.local[697]: ========                                                                                                        
[   45.856200] rc.local[697]: PARAMETERS                                                                                                      
[   45.858119] rc.local[697]:  * /rosdistro: melodic                                                                                          
[   45.864191] rc.local[697]:  * /rosversion: 1.14.3                                                                                          
[   45.868300] rc.local[697]: NODES                                                                                                           
[   45.869775] rc.local[697]:   /                                                                                                             
[   45.876248] rc.local[697]:     LCD (electronicload/LCD.py)                                                                                 
[   45.877776] rc.local[697]:     controller (electronicload/controller.py)                                                                   
[   45.880181] rc.local[697]:     logger_to_file (electronicload/logger_to_file.py)                                                           
[   45.882618] rc.local[697]:     sensors (electronicload/sensors.py)                                                                         
[   45.885431] rc.local[697]:     shutdown (electronicload/shutdown.py)                                                                       
[   45.888739] rc.local[697]: auto-starting new master                                                                                        
[   45.900295] rc.local[697]: process[master]: started with pid [1190]                                                                        
[   45.991327] rc.local[697]: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                              
[   45.996615] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rosmaster", line 35, in <module>                                                   
[   45.999477] rc.local[697]:     rosmaster.rosmaster_main()                                                                                  
[   46.002388] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 84, in rosmaster_main             
[   46.009036] rc.local[697]:     configure_logging()                                                                                         
[   46.013041] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 58, in configure_logging          
[   46.020393] rc.local[697]:     _log_filename = rosgraph.roslogging.configure_logging('rosmaster', logging.DEBUG, filename=filename)        
[   46.022597] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 185, in configure_logging    
[   46.026729] rc.local[697]:     logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)                                      
[   46.037566] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 85, in fileConfig                                           
[   46.038724] rc.local[697]:     handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)                                                                
[   46.039760] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 163, in _install_handlers                                   
[   46.041525] rc.local[697]:     h = klass(*args)                                                                                            
[   46.044332] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 230, in __init__             
[   46.052325] rc.local[697]:     from rospy.rostime import get_time, is_wallclock                                                            
[   46.053851] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>                   
[   46.056647] rc.local[697]:     from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \                                                              
[   46.059883] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>                     
[   46.068330] rc.local[697]:     import roslib                                                                                               
[   46.072202] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>                  
[   46.073679] rc.local[697]:     import roslib.stacks                                                                                        
[   46.076234] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/stacks.py", line 46, in <module>                    
[   46.077548] rc.local[697]:     import roslib.packages                                                                                      
[   46.080188] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 49, in <module>                  
[   46.088201] rc.local[697]:     from catkin.find_in_workspaces import find_in_workspaces as catkin_find                                     
[   46.092295] rc.local[697]:   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 36, in <module>        
[   46.093890] rc.local[697]:     from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages                                                               
[   46.096299] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 38, in <module>                          
[   46.104211] rc.local[697]:     from .package import _get_package_xml                                                                       
[   46.105809] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 43, in <module>                           
[   46.106964] rc.local[697]:     from catkin_pkg.condition import evaluate_condition                                                         
[   46.112210] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/condition.py", line 17, in <module>                         
[   46.116278] rc.local[697]:     import pyparsing                                                                                            
[   46.117832] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyparsing.py", line 5344, in <module>                                  
[   46.118993] rc.local[697]:     commonHTMLEntity = Regex('&(?P<entity>' + '|'.join(_htmlEntityMap.keys()) +");").setName("common HTML entity
")                                                                                                                                            
[   46.125052] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2770, in __init__                                  
[   46.128187] rc.local[697]:     self.re = re.compile(self.pattern, self.flags)                                                              
[   46.132269] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile                                                         
[   46.136213] rc.local[697]:     return _compile(pattern, flags)                                                                             
[   46.137679] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 249, in _compile                                                        
[   46.144218] rc.local[697]:     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)                                                                     
[   46.148298] rc.local[697]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 595, in compile                                                
[   46.149888] rc.local[697]:     groupindex, indexgroup                                                                                      
[   46.151047] rc.local[697]: KeyboardInterrupt                                                                                               
[   47.091950] rc.local[697]: [master] killing on exit
```

Everything still works when running them AFTER boot up.
Everything still works when the beaglebone boots WITHOUT the Ethernet connection.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321574/problem-with-roslaunch-on-rc.local-startup/) by [Jason C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/40572/jason-c./) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-05-02**:
Do you have other options than using `rclocal` ? If so [#q290599](https://answers.ros.org/question/290599/how-to-run-roscore-or-roslaunch-when-i-boot/) might help you launch nodes on startup (but not using `rclocal`).

**Comment by [Jason C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/40572/jason-c./) on 2019-05-03**:
@Delb I tried systemd service but had the same results. I found a way around, if you are interested you can check the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I could not find a clear solution to the issue, with Delb's help I tweaked around the setup.bash script and found out that the roscore that is being automatically called from roslaunch may be the source of the problem. Using the `--wait` parameter on roslaunch, I can raise my own roscore and then run all the nodes needed. This is my new startup.bash file:

```
#! /bin/bash
##########################
##   scipt starts here  ##
##########################

export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311/"
export ROS_HOSTNAME="localhost"


echo "The penguin took off..."

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source /home/tucer/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
echo "...the penguin sourced both bash files for ros with his penguin nades..."
roscore&
roslaunch --wait electronicload launcher.launch

echo "...the penguin landed safely."
```

EDIT: typo.

---

Originally posted by [Jason C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/40572/jason-c./) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-05-03**:
Glad you solved your issue !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this is your exact problem but there is something odd :

```
ERROR: could not contact master [http://localhost:11311]
```

This suggests that the environment variable `ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to `http://localhost:11311`.

```
started roslaunch server http://arm:45779/
```

This suggests that the environment variable `ROS_HOSTNAME` is set to `arm`.

Not having those variables to the same value is a common source of issue especially if the master is runned on your laptop.

Maybe you should try adding at the beginning of your `startup.bash` file those two lines :

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:11311/"
export ROS_HOSTNAME="YOUR_IP_ADDRESS"
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jason C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/40572/jason-c./) on 2019-05-02**:
thanks for the advice, however errors still exist. edited OP with information (EDIT2).